# Simple Data Table Update and Page Integration

Tags: plugins, sort, columns, table

There are a variety of tables (page-level, not database) in a website I manage that need to be regularly updated. The difficult issue is that this information is often only one or two data columns, so I usually snake the data into multiple columns. [Here is an example.](http://ooga.org/events/ooga-events/2012-ooga-winter-meeting/sponsors/) This reduces scrolling and fills the page much better, but it is very tedious to update by hand! I currently create the table in the editor using [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) and then shift the cells by hand whenever new data is entered.

For another example, I have a list of about 200 corporate members, which would be great to display in a table (even sortable and paged), but I only have two columns, the company name and logo. I would really like to be able to snake this into four columns to fill the page and avoid scrolling. That said, I also need a solution that is not time consuming to update!

I looked into [WP-Tables Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/), but this does not seem to have the ability to snake columns. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not convert them into custom types or taxs? You can do anything you want then. Otherwise, your best bet is to use lists and css like mentioned in below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't think this is really a WordPress question, I'll go ahead and answer anyway. ;-)

I think you'd be much better off using an unordered list and some css to get the 2 column effect you're looking for without much effort when updating.

The markup for your lists would look something like this:

```
<ul id="twocol">
  <li>Sponsor 1</li>
  <li>Sponsor 2</li>
  <li>Sponsor 3</li>
  <li>Etc...</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS would be something like this:

```
ul{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
li{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
#twocol li  { width:50%;}
```

Obviously, some styling would be required to match your current table colors, etc...  But this would give you 2 columns with the "snakeing" effect you're looking for.